# Space between div items gets exponentially larger with each new div

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Forgive me if I use incorrect terms or lingo as I'm new to programming. This is difficult to explain, but in my RoR application, I have a page dedicated to vendor information. For some reason the space between the bootstrap panels that they are inside gets exponentially larger and larger with each new vendor item that gets added to the page. Also, the vertical alignment drops each time, almost as if the items are nesting inside of each other. I've searched all over SO for the past few hours and haven't found a working solution. See code below:

index.html.erb - Index view for Vendor Model

```
<div id="vendors" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @vendors.each do |vendor| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
      <%= link_to image_tag(vendor.vendor_image.url), vendor %>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= vendor.vendor_name %><br/>
        <strong><%= vendor.description %></strong><br/>
        <%= vendor.contact_name %><br/>
        <%= vendor.phone_num %><br/>
        <%= vendor.user.email if vendor.user %><br/>
        <% if vendor.vc_one_url %>
          <%= vendor.vc_one_desc %><br/>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_two_url %>
          <%= vendor.vc_two_desc %><br/>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_three_url %>
          <%= vendor.vc_three_desc %><br/>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_four_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_five_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_six_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_seven_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_eight_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_nine_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_ten_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_eleven_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_twelve_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_thirteen_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_fourteen_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <% if vendor.vc_fifteen_url %>
          <%= link_to "Vendor Correspondence", vendor.vc_one_url %><br/>
        <% end %>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_vendor_path(vendor) %>
          <%= link_to 'Destroy', vendor, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have another view for a different model (Pins) that I am trying to do the same thing on and it works perfectly. Every item sits flush against the other items and there are no issues. This file is included below:

texaspins.html.erb - View for Pins Model (works perfectly)

```
<div class="well"><h3>Issues</h3></div>
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <% if pin.state_id == "TX" %>
      <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url), pin %>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= pin.state_id %><br/>
          <%= pin.reso_item %><br/>
          <strong><%= pin.description %></strong><br/>
          <%= pin.user.email if pin.user %><br/>
          <% if pin.genres_doc_url %>
          <%= link_to "General Research", pin.genres_doc_url %><br/>
          <% end %>
          <% if pin.attachment_url %>
            <%= link_to "Letter Ruling", pin.attachment_url %><br/>
          <% end %>
          <% if pin.invoice_example_one_url %>
            <%= link_to "Invoice Example", pin.invoice_example_one_url %><br/>
          <% end %>
          <% if pin.invoice_example_two_url %>
            <%= link_to "Invoice Example", pin.invoice_example_two_url %><br/>
          <% end %>
          <% if pin.invoice_example_three_url %>
            <%= link_to "Invoice Example", pin.invoice_example_three_url %>
          <% end %>
          <% if pin.user == current_user %>
            <div class="actions">
              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
              <%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help and let me know if I need to include any more files to further clarify my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ruby on rails, but it looks like your last `<% end %>` is in the wrong place and you will end up with nested `<div>`s. I guess not really nested because they won't be closed properly. I'm guessing that last one is to close out the `each` command so it should be before the last `</div>`, like in your example that works.

Comment: That solved my issue. Thank you for your time and help, Peterjb, I greatly appreciate it.